# mysql connection Can not read response from server

Tags: mysql, spring, mybatis, druid

MySQL 5.7, a transaction is running but thread is sleeping, client request(tomcat) is blocking, it will last for many many seconds, after killing connection in MySQL, tomcat receives below exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 852,932 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 857,937 milliseconds ago.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:82)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:230)
......

 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2222)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:470)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3109)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2334)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2733)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1192)
......

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 20,481 bytes, read 19,682 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3008)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2205)
```

I use alibaba druid Connection Pool, testOnBorrow=true, mysql java driver version is 5.1.40

The above exception is thrown after connection is killed, tomcat is blocking until the connection is killed.

This case occurs several times in production evn, it is hard to repeat in develop env.

As the caused exception is `Can not read response from server. Expected to read 20,481 bytes, read 19,682 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.`, client is waiting for more data from server, so I guess the connection borrowed from pool is valid at first, but why can't reading more data from server?

BTW: we recently use MySQL /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(xxx) */ optimizer hint.  MySQL will throw Exception if query is timeout, I don't know whether it is related with my problem, but I guess it should not.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your query from your servlet ran for longer than your MAX_EXECUTION_TIME. At any rate, it looks like your query timed out when it had been running for 853 seconds.

And, your servlet crashed. The error trace you provided shows what happened.

If you want your servlet to recover from having its JDBC connections killed, you must program it to catch an exception when you KILL its database process, and then repeat the query.

You'll have to do some experimenting to get this right.

You can force the failure in development by using a much shorter  MAX_EXECUTION_TIME. Or you can access your development MySQL server with a command client, look up the processid of the process serving your spring servlet, and `KILL` it manually.

The root cause: I believe your query takes far too long. You must optimize it somehow. Look at [query-performance](/questions/tagged/query-performance) for ideas about that.

Comment: first thanks for your reply. As some user's data is big, query may actually timeout, so I add MAX_EXECUTION_TIME  to decrease database load. after connection killed, servlet crashed, I catch exception and tell user to narrow  query range, This is what I am doing.  Now problem is that: connection is now killed by dba administrator manually, this is inconvenient. though I can write a daemon task to minitor long query connection and kill it automatically.

Comment: But there is one thing that confused me:Either MySQL send me full data or throw exception(as query timeout), it now gives me part of data and blocks me to wait for rest of data, is this MySQL's mechanism or data is lost after MySQL writing?